# How to use QSGGeometryNode without causing a memory leak and ensure correct clean up

Tags: c++, qt, qml, scenegraph, qsgclipnode

I using a `QSGGeometry`, `QSGVertexColorMaterial` & a `QSGGeometryNode` to draw something real time on my `QQuickItem` derived class that is `MyQuickItem` here.

Following is my `updatePaintNode` method where the crux of the repaint logic lies.

```
QSGNode * MyQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData * updatePaintNodeData) {

  if (!oldNode) {
    oldNode = new QSGNode;
  }

  oldNode->removeAllChildNodes();

  QSGGeometry * geometry = GetMyGeometry();
  QSGVertexColorMaterial * material = new QSGVertexColorMaterial;
  QSGGeometryNode * child_node = new QSGGeometryNode;

  child_node->setGeometry(geometry);
  child_node->setMaterial(material);
  child_node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial);
  oldNode->appendChildNode(child_node);

  return oldNode;
}
```

**Issue:**
Above **logic works great**. No problem with functionality at all. No performance issues as well. **But I worried that I am causing memory leaks**. Look at following two lines in the above method `updatePaintNode` where I allocate raw pointers.

```
QSGVertexColorMaterial * material = new QSGVertexColorMaterial;
QSGGeometryNode * child_node = new QSGGeometryNode;
```

I allocate them & I do not delete them. This is because the point where they should be deleted is after `updatePaintNode` finishes. *And thats not under my control.*

**Question:**
How can I ensure that the 2 pointers `material` & `child_node` are cleared from memory correctly?
Does doing a `child_node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial)` like I am doing above sets the **ownership of the pointers** to QtSceneGraph & relieve me of the burden of deleting the pointers?

**Secondary Question:**
I am using `oldNode->removeAllChildNodes()` to clear the data drawn in the previous frame. Is this a good way to clear previous data on screen before painting new data?

**PS:**
I reiterate: There are no performance issues with this implementation. I just want to be sure that I am not causing any memory leaks. I have tried using `material` & `child_node` as smart pointers like so:

```
auto material = std::make_shared<QSGVertexColorMaterial>();
auto child_node = new std::make_shared<QSGGeometryNode>();
```

But this causes a crash when `material` & `child_node` are auto-cleared from memory at a later point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in your example code you can rely on the automatic cleanup of nodes. You are not leaking memory from updatePaintNode.

**oldnode and child_node**

`oldnode` returned from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode() is automatically deleted on the right thread at the right time. Trees of QSGNode instances are managed through the use of QSGNode::OwnedByParent, which is set by default.

**material**

Because you have set the flag QSGNode::OwnsMaterial for your child_node `material` is deleted when child_node is deleted.

**Second question**: Is this a good way?

The answer is no. There is no point of creating and deleting nodes every time the scene is rendered. Instead, you should reuse the node/nodes. In the below example code I'm assuming that geometry changes but material doesn't change during the lifetime of the QQuickItem. If the material changes you may need to call *node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyMaterial)*. Note that only one node is created, and it's created only once (unless e.g. window hidden and then brought back to fg or something else).

```
QSGNode * MyQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData * updatePaintNodeData) {

    QSGGeometryNode *node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(oldNode);
    if (!node) {
        node = new QSGGeometryNode;

        QSGVertexColorMaterial * material = new QSGVertexColorMaterial;
        node->setMaterial(material);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial);
    }

    // if GetMyGeometry returns every time a new dynamically allocated object then you should
    // call node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry) to not leak memory here:
    QSGGeometry * geometry = GetMyGeometry(); 
    node->setGeometry(geometry);
    // No need to call node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry) because setGeometry is called.

    return node;
}
```